# Vaadin 8 Grid select first row

Tags: vaadin8

Is there a simple way to select the first row shown in a `Grid`? I have of list of items and use the `DataProvider.ofCollection(items)` data provider. Simply selecting the first item of my backing list is not sufficient because I sort the `Grid` by one column which could make a different order than in the original list. Any idea?

I could use `DataProvider.fetch` method but it feels too complicated. Is there no built-in way?

Comment: As far as I've seen it's not possible by simple means, eg `selectByIndex(0)`. I tried to work around it by switching to multi-select-mode, select all items, get the selection and use the first item, but unfortunately the order in the set of selected items that you get, is not the same as in the UI, so that's also a bust. Nonetheless, if you get your data from a DB and it comes sorted as a result of the query, you could use the first item. Otherwise you can try opening an [issue with the Vaadin team](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is get the current sort Column Id and SortDirection, then with your data, sort and find the next object to select.

For me, I had the same issue with TreeGrid (extends Grid) so this will be similar, minus the TreeData/RootItems part. Also, I only had sorting on "name".

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->    
List<GridSortOrder<MyPojo>> order = grid.getSortOrder();
Column<MyPojo, ?> col = order.get(0).getSorted();
SortDirection dir = order.get(0).getDirection();
String colId = col.getId();

if(colId.equals("name")) {
    Optional<MyPojo> first;
    if(dir.equals(SortDirection.ASCENDING)) {
        first = grid.getTreeData().getRootItems().stream()
                                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyPojo::getName)).findFirst();
    }else {
        first = grid.getTreeData().getRootItems().stream()
                                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyPojo::getName).reversed()).findFirst();
    }
    if(first.isPresent())
        grid.select(first.get());
}
```

Comment: Yes, at the moment there is no other simpler solution.